# sql 2008 error 'the column prod_desc1 was specified multiple times for "a"'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've got this ginormous sql select statement I'm using in a SSRS 2008 report.  I need field "prod_desc1" from the Product table, but also the same named field from Order_Line.  I've aliased both of them but I'm still getting the error.  Here's my statment:

```
   SELECT     order_num, quote_num, cust_num, cust_desc, ship_via_desc, whse_desc, slsm_desc, ar_term_desc, vend_desc, pline_desc, major_grp, cust_po_num, ord_date, req_date, shp_date, ord_type,  tot_ord_$, pline_num,  prod_num, price_ext, STATUS, prod_desc1 as prod_desc, prod_desc1 as com1, prod_desc2 as com2, net_price, seq_num
FROM         (SELECT     o.order_num, o.quote_num, o.cust_num, c.cust_desc, s.ship_via_desc, w.whse_desc, sa.slsm_desc, t.ar_term_desc, v.vend_desc, ca.pline_desc, ca.major_grp, o.cust_po_num, o.ord_date, o.req_date, o.shp_date, o.ord_type,  o.tot_ord_$, ol. pline_num, ol.prod_num, price_ext, 'Open' AS STATUS, p.prod_desc1, ol.prod_desc1, ol.prod_desc2, ol.net_price, seq_num
                       FROM          [ORDER]  o
left outer join order_line ol on o.order_num = ol.order_num
left outer join product p on ol.prod_num = p.prod_num
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no 
left outer join ship_via s on o.ship_via_num = s.ship_via_id
left outer join whse_addr w on o.shp_whse = w.whse_num 
left outer join salesman sa on o.slsm2_num = sa.slsm_num
left outer join terms t on o.ar_term_num = t.ar_term_num
left outer join vend v on ol.prim_vend_num = v.vend_num
left outer join category ca on ol.pline_Num = ca.pline_Id
WHERE  (@OrderNum is null OR o.order_num = (@OrderNum)) and
o.cust_num IN (@CustomerNumber) and 
(ol.prim_vend_num IN (@VendNum) or ol.prim_vend_num is NULL) and
o.req_date between (@ReqDateFrom) and (@ReqDateTo) and
o.ord_date between (@EntDateFrom) and (@EntDateTo) and
(c.slsm_num =  (@SlsmnRealNum) and ol.major_grp IN ('C', 'R', 'W') or c.slsm2_num =  (@SlsmnRealNum) and ol.major_grp IN ('P', 'S')) and
ol.major_grp IN (@MajorGrp) and
ol.pline_num IN (@ProductLine) and
(@PONum is null OR o.cust_po_num LIKE ('%' + @PONum + '%')) and
(@ItemNum is null OR ol.prod_num = (@ItemNum))
UNION ALL
SELECT     o.order_num, o.quote_num, o.cust_num, c.cust_desc, s.ship_via_desc, w.whse_desc, sa.slsm_desc, t.ar_term_desc, v.vend_desc, ca.pline_desc, ca.major_grp, o.cust_po_num, o.ord_date, o.req_date, o.shp_date, o.ord_type,  o.tot_ord_$, ol.pline_num,  ol.prod_num, net_ext,  'Closed' AS STATUS,  p.prod_desc1, ol.prod_desc1, ol.prod_desc2, ol.net_price, seq_num
                       FROM         ORDER_HISTORY  o
left outer join order_history_line ol on o.order_num = ol.order_num
left outer join product p on ol.prod_num = p.prod_num
left outer join customer c on o.cust_num = c.cust_no
left outer join ship_via s on o.ship_via_num = s.ship_via_id
left outer join whse_addr w on o.shp_whse = w.whse_num 
left outer join salesman sa on o.slsm2_num = sa.slsm_num
left outer join terms t on o.ar_term_num = t.ar_term_num
left outer join vend v on ol.prim_vend_num = v.vend_num
left outer join category ca on ol.pline_Num = ca.pline_Id
WHERE (@OrderNum is null OR o.order_num = (@OrderNum)) and
o.cust_num IN (@CustomerNumber) and 
(ol.prim_vend_num IN (@VendNum) or ol.prim_vend_num is NULL) and
o.req_date between (@ReqDateFrom) and (@ReqDateTo) and
o.ord_date between (@EntDateFrom) and (@EntDateTo) and
(c.slsm_num =  (@SlsmnRealNum) and ol.major_grp IN ('C', 'R', 'W') or c.slsm2_num =  (@SlsmnRealNum) and ol.major_grp IN ('P', 'S')) and
ol.major_grp IN (@MajorGrp) and
ol.pline_num IN (@ProductLine) and
(@PONum is null OR o.cust_po_num LIKE ('%' + @PONum + '%')) and
(@ItemNum is null OR ol.prod_num = (@ItemNum))) as a
WHERE  (STATUS = CASE WHEN @OrderType = 'Both' THEN STATUS ELSE @OrderType END)  ORDER BY cust_desc, req_date, vend_desc
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: You are specifying them correctly inside the nested query, but the outer select doesn't know about the tables in the nested query; it only sees the output of the nested query as a table. This table it sees currently has two columns named the same. If you need them returned in the end as the same name, alias one of them as something different inside the nested subquery and then alias it back to the same name in the outer select.

Comment: @Love2Learn -- thanks!  but I'm a little confused at what to do.  Do I change ol.prod_desc as com1 (ol = order line) in just the nested part of the query?

Comment: @Love2Learn -- got it!  change the outer select to "prod_desc, com1, prod_desc2" and in the 2 nested selects, "ol.prod_Desc1 as com1".  Thanks!!! :)